# A push style parser combinator in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

Usually, parser combinators in Haskell based on the parser type like

```
newtype Parser t r = Parser ([t] -> [(r,[t])])
```

This allows back tracking and multiple results. However I think it would be good to have it in "push" style, means the parser will have a set of result when no more input given, and have a transition function that for a given token, results in a new state of the parser. This results in the defintion

```
newtype PushParser t r = PushParser ([r], Maybe (t -> PushParser t r))
```

(We could have a data constructor that have two fields, however I prefer to use the more efficient `newtype` keyword so have to have only one field as a tuple)

To parse a list of tokens, we define the `parse` function as following:

```
parse :: PushParser t r -> [t] -> [r]
--No input, rs is the result
parse ~(PushParser (rs, _)) [] = rs
--No parsing function, this is an error state. No result
parse (PushParser (_,Nothing)) _ = []
--Otherwise, drop the results, apply the pasing function with the input and continue
parse (PushParser (_,Just f)) (t:ts) = parse (f t) ts
```

We can then define a `fmap` to make it a `Functor` like the following:

```
instance Functor (PushParser t) where
    fmap f ~(PushParser (r,mg)) = PushParser ((map f r), do {g<-mg; return (fmap f.g)})
```

Instance of `Applicative` is more tricky, but the easiest way is to make it depend on the not yet implemented instance of `Monad`.

```
instance Applicative (PushParser t) where
    pure x = PushParser ([x],Nothing)
    pf <*> pv = do 
        f <- pf
        v <- pv
        return (f v)
```

But before giving the definition of `Monad` I want to introduce the definition of `Alternative`:

```
instance Alternative (PushParser t) where
    empty = PushParser ([],Nothing)
    (PushParser (r1,Nothing)) <|> (PushParser (r2,f)) = PushParser ((r1++r2), f)
    (PushParser (r1,f)) <|> (PushParser (r2,Nothing)) = PushParser ((r1++r2), f)
    (PushParser (r1,Just f1)) <|> (PushParser (r2,Just f2)) =
        PushParser ((r1 ++ r2), Just (\t -> f1 t <|> f2 t))
```

I have tried out different ways for the instance of `Monad`, but finally I believe the best way to give definition of `(>>=)` is to define `unwrap` (or `join` in the monad library) first.

```
instance Monad (PushParser t) where
    p >>= f = unwrap (fmap f p) where 
        unwrap ~(PushParser (prs, mf)) = 
            foldr (<|>) (PushParser ([], do { f<-mf; return (unwrap.f)})) prs
```

The above works perfectally fine, and although it does not make sense to make it an instance of `Parser` (in `Text.Parser.Combinators`) as we don't allow trace back, the other combinators that only requires `Alternative` worked perfectally fine.

However, the performance seems to be too bad. It is possibly as it keeps all possible parsing path and so consumes too much memory. For example, a simple `parse (many (some (char '.'))) "...."` will return 8 results, with all combinations of dots.

But I think there should be some way to improve the performance. Please advise me how to improve on this.

Comment: Did you mean to write `newtype PushParser t r = PushParser ([r], Maybe (t -> PushParser t r))`?

Comment: But when the second argument of `parse` is `[]`, how can you return the `[t]` from the first argument as an `[r]`? Also tuples can't possibly be faster than `data`-constructed types: [Tuples are defined using `data`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Tuple.html#%28%2C%29)

Comment: That's correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It'll lazily take no more memory than it takes time to find the first result if you do not try to enumerate all possible results.

For `many`/`some` to only try one option, you want `Maybe`'s `Alternative`/`MonadPlus` behavior, not `[]`'s. You could parametrize your Parser type in the `Alternative` used so the user can change it on the fly.

[yoctoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yoctoparsec) uses this "push" style.

```
parseString (hoistFreeT maybeToList $ many $ some $ mfilter (=='.') token) "...."
```